# If second quartile is equal to fourth quartile can we prove the third quartile?

Tags: probability-distributions

Given than the Q2 = Q4 = 17
but the sample size is 15, but the elements and the Q3 is unknown

Can we just say the Q3 = 17?

Comment: Obviously, since $Q_2\le Q_3 \le Q_4$.

Comment: This is about probability-distributions, not distribution-theory. Tag changed.